# Laravel permission still allowing me to access a page

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-permission

I'm trying to stop a user from accessing a page. I'm using https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction in my laravel app.

The problem I'm having is that the user is still able to access the page even when the permission is turned off.

So I have a page called user-info.blade.php that allows a user to read and update a user's info and only specific people are able to do it.

I have 2 permissions `manage users` and `view users`. `manage users` allows you to update and delete a user where as the `view users` only lets you view them.

The problem I'm having is when I switch `manage users` off for a user that user can still access that page. All my UI stuff disappears, like my buttons, but
if I go to that page directly from the url I can still access it.

This is in my `api.php`

```
Route::get('/manage-users', [ UserController::class, 'manageUsers'])->middleware('can:manage users');
Route::get('/users', [ UserController::class, 'getUsers'])->middleware('can:view users');
```

I'm not sure what other code to add to my question or what other information to give.

Answer (score 0):

*(I would rather put my answer as a comment but since I'm unable to comment I'm posting it as an answer.)*

If I understand your **user-info.blade.php** page is accessible for both `manage users` and `view users` permissions. If that's the case, turning off `manage users` permission will only prevent them from updating the information, they will still be able to view data (meaning they are able to access the page ) . You probably need to turn off `view users` too if you don't want them to access the page.

And I don't understand why you are using `api` to prevent users from accessing a page.